# Show "Cash on delivery" method for AZ state using payment-service.js mixin

Tags: magento2, javascript, mixins

I am stuck. Can someone please correct my code?

```
define([
'underscore',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list',
'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
'mage/utils/wrapper',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
], function (_, methodList, selectPaymentMethod, wrapper, quote) {
'use strict';

var isCashOnDeliveryMethod = function (paymentMethod) {
    return paymentMethod.method === 'cashondelivery';
}
return function (paymentService) {




    var setPaymentMethods = paymentService.setPaymentMethods;
    setPaymentMethods = wrapper.wrap(setPaymentMethods, function(original,methods){
        console.log('before');
        var result = original();
        var state = quote.shippingAddress().regionCode;
        console.log(state);
        if(state != "AZ"){
            var cod = _.find(methods, isCashOnDeliveryMethod);
            methods = _.without(methods, cod);
            console.log(methods)
            console.log(methodList(methods));

        }
        selectPaymentMethod(methods);
        console.log('after');
        return setPaymentMethods.apply(this, arguments);
        // return setPaymentMethods;
        // return result;
    });

    paymentService.setPaymentMethods = setPaymentMethods;

    var getAvailablePaymentMethods = paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods;
    getAvailablePaymentMethods = wrapper.wrap(getAvailablePaymentMethods, function(original,allMethods){
        // var state = quote.shippingAddress().regionCode;
        // console.log(state)
        console.log('before avail');
        // console.log(quote.shippingAddress().regionCode);
        var result = original();
        console.log('after avail');
        console.log(allMethods);
        // return result;
        return getAvailablePaymentMethods.apply(this, arguments)
    });

    paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods = getAvailablePaymentMethods;
    return paymentService;
};


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
define([
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method',
    'mage/utils/wrapper',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
], function (_, selectPaymentMethod, wrapper, quote) {
    'use strict';

    return function (paymentService) {
        let cashOnDeliveryCode = 'cashondelivery',
            isCashOnDeliveryMethod = function (paymentMethod) {
                return paymentMethod.method === cashOnDeliveryCode;
            },
            isCashOnDeliveryRegion = function () {
                return quote.shippingAddress() && quote.shippingAddress().regionCode === 'CA';
            };

        paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods = wrapper.wrap(paymentService.getAvailablePaymentMethods, function (_super) {
            let methods = _super();
            if (!isCashOnDeliveryRegion()) {
                return _.reject(methods, isCashOnDeliveryMethod);
            }

            return methods;
        });

        paymentService.setPaymentMethods = wrapper.wrap(paymentService.setPaymentMethods, function (_super, methods) {
            if (isCashOnDeliveryRegion()) {
                // select method by default
                if (quote.paymentMethod()) {
                    quote.paymentMethod().method = cashOnDeliveryCode;
                }
                let cashOnDeliveryMethod = _.find(methods, isCashOnDeliveryMethod);
                selectPaymentMethod(cashOnDeliveryMethod);
            } else {
                methods = _.reject(methods, isCashOnDeliveryMethod);
            }

            return _super(methods);
        });

        return paymentService;
    }
});
```

Comment: Victor. you're awesome!